# Hide div when the page is loaded and show when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I took [**this simple code**](https://coderwall.com/p/3uwgga/make-css-dropdown-menus-work-on-touch-devices) for drop down menu and it's working so far. The problem is that when I load the page, #drop menu is displayed, which is obviously not what we want. The goal is to show the #drop menu when #submenu link is clicked, not immediately.

I modified my code below, because I need a div element, not a list.

js

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('#submenu').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#drop').toggle();
    });

    $(document).click( function(){
        $('#drop').hide();
    });

});
```

html

```
<a href="#" id = "submenu">Products</a>
   <div id = "drop" >
     DROP DOWN MENU
   </div>
```

Comment: `#drop { display: none; }` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some css:

```
#drop { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

just put this code in your dropdown.

```
 <a href="#" id = "submenu">Products</a>

 <div id = "drop" style="display:none;">

  DROP DOWN MENU

 </div>
```

and your problem will be resolved when page load drop div will be hidden that u can use toggle or show command in jquery function.

Regards

Imran Qasim

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want your element to be displaced when the page first loads, why not set its visibilty to hidden in the html, like `style="visbility:hidden"`,and assign `submenu link` an action listener function and reference this element via getElementById and set its visibility to visible. 
`document.getElementbyId("dropDownMenu").style.visibility = "visible"`

Answer (score 1):

If you dont't want to use css then you can do it  with jquery.

```
<a href="#" id = "submenu">Products</a>
  <div id = "drop" >
   DROP DOWN MENU
  </div>  


<scitpt type="text/javascipt">
    $(document).ready( function(){
      $('#drop').hide();

    $('#submenu').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#drop').toggle();

    });

    $(document).click( function(){
    $('#drop').hide();
    });

   })
 </script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbo5dx00/)